# What does CTL in rabbitmqctl stand for?

Tags: rabbitmq

In the docs it refers to it as the `command line tool` but that's `clt` not `ctl`.

Comment: Here ctl stands for "Control", because you use it to *control* RabbitMQ.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

RabbitMQ has a bunch of command line tools, one of which is `RabbitMQCtl`.

The `ctl` part stands for `control`. You use it to *control* RabbitMQ for general administrative/operator tasks.

Comment: Oh Thank you. Why the hell this didn't came to my mind.